# Send List to React JSX

Tags: c#, reactjs, reactjs.net

Hi I´m new to React and want to pass a of List from C# to React and and render the first image in the list.

I´ve populated a list and passed it to a view.

```
  @Html.React("Components.ImageFullWidth", new  { topImages = Model.Images })
```

How do I access the list from here?

```
class ImageFullWidth extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
        <picture>
            <source src={}/>
        </picture>
    );
}
};

module.exports = ImageFullWidth;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data sent from `ASP.NET` via the component's `props`, like so: `this.props.topImages`.

You can then write: `<source src={this.props.topImages[0]}`. That seems to be the way [`ReactJs.NET`](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html) seems to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you created the component passing the props topImages, you need to receive it in your Component.

[React State Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/components-props-and-state.html#state) can help you there. But basically is this

```
class ImagesFullWidth extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props); 
        this.state = {topImages: props.topImages}; 
     }
     render() {
         let topImages = this.state.topImages ? this.state.topImages : [];
        return topImages.map((imgSrc) =>
            <picture>
                <source src={imgSrc} />
            </picture>
        );
     }
};
```